# Pull comments from Facebook API (Python, JSON)

Tags: python, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pull all comments from all posts the last 24 hours using the Facebook API. Currently, I can only pull from a certain data range of posts as the Facebook API only allows "since" and "until" to be used under posts. I can't seem to use those parameters for comments. So for example, with my code currently, I cannot pull today's comments from a post that was posted in April. **Has anyone been able to pull comments from all posts in the last 24 hours without including the posts?** This is my code so far:

```
import facebook
import requests
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
import time

now = 1439769600
thyme = int(time.time())
since = int((thyme - 0.7 * 60 * 1000))

user = 'INSERT USER ID/NUMBER'
access_token = 'INSERT ACCESS TOKEN'
url = ' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/' + user + '?fields=posts.until' + '(' + str(now) + ')' + '.since' + '(' + str(since) + ')' + '.limit(100)%7Bcreated_time%2Cmessage%2Ccomments.limit(1000)%7Bcreated_time%2Cmessage%7D%7D&access_token='

html = url + access_token
print html

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(html))
with open('here.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    json.dump(data, textfile)
```

Comment: You should use whatever pagination logic returned by the initial call (let it be cursors or time pagination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries I came up with the code that solves everything for me:

```
import facebook
import requests
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

#def some_action(post):
    #print posts['data']
 #   print(post['created_time'])

access_token = 'ENTER ACCESS TOKEN'
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/ENTER FACEBOOK USERNAME/IDNUMBER FOLLOWED BY ?fields=posts.since(1406851200).limit(50)%7Bcreated_time%2Cmessage%2Ccomments.limit(2000)%7Bcreated_time%2Cmessage%7D%7D&access_token='

html = url + access_token

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(html))
with open('penguin.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    json.dump(data, textfile)
```